# How to implement or in a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, rest

I am trying to query information by entering either value 1 or value 2 from the database. Here is the body of the request:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "Value1": {"$regex": "222"}
      "value2": {"regex":"359"}
    
  }

}
```

I tried:

```json
{
  "query": {
"$or": [
    "Value1": {"$regex": "222"},
      "value2": {"regex":"359"}
]
    
  }

}
```

expecting a response of either value1 or value2

Answer (score 0):

You can check the details of **"or operator"** from the mongodb docs:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

```
{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }

db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] } )
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), MongoDB `$or` operator accepts array of conditions, while you pass conditions as one object.

The correct syntax would be like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "Value1": {
        "$regex": "222"
      }
    },
    {
      "value2": {
        "$regex": "359"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is a [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FAchfLLhGRU) to playground to see query work.

Also, you seem to have tried passing array already, but you made a mistake in second condition. You had `regex` while the proper operator name is `$regex`, like in your first condition.